# jQuery validate--don't validate until user input entered and field blurred at least once

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

If you take a look at this form:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example

You'll notice one problem: it immediately triggers field validation after you enter a single keystroke in any textbox.  For instance, if you start typing in the email field, after a single keystroke you will get a validation error.

This seems in direct contradiction to the descriptive text below the example form, which says:

> Before a field is marked as invalid, the validation is lazy: Before submitting the form for the first time, the user can tab through fields without getting annoying messages - he won't get bugged before he had the chance to actually enter a correct value
>
> Once a field was marked invalid, it is eagerly validated: As soon as the user entered the necessary value, the error message is removed
>
> If the user enters something in a non-marked field, and tabs/clicks away from it (blur the field), it is validated - obviously the user had the intention to enter something, but failed to enter the correct value

This describes the desired behavior--no "annoying error messages" until the user either a) submits the form or b) enters data into a field and blurs the field.  But what is actually happening in the demo is that validation is triggered after the first keystroke, and not after the field is blurred.  Thus, the user is bombarded with "annoying error messages" that distract him from what he's doing.  We want happy users, not annoyed users :-)

How can I get the behavior described in the text, rather than the behavior in the demo?

Thanks!

-Josh

Answer (score 0):

The Default behavior is it does a live validation. To override this just add a parameter

onkeyup:false like this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentForm").validate({
      "onkeyup":false
      });
  });
```

here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tCVky/)

Comment: Why does the text describing how it works make it sound like this is *not* the default behavior?  Was there a change and the documentation is out of date?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't give the desired behavior, which is to start doing live validation once the user has entered input into the field *and* blurred it at least once.  This prevents the "annoying messages" from displaying while, e.g., the user types in his email address.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't have to do anything to prevent from messages as soon as you "enter" the input field.

I am using form-validation jQuery plugin.

Here is an example of my code, it only validates when you write something in the input. If you write something and then erase it just in that case the "required message" field will appear:

**Js snippet**

```
 form2.validate({
                 rules: {
                    name: {
                      required: true,
                      minlength: 2,
                      maxlength: 50,
                    },

                    lastname: {
                      required: true,
                      minlength: 2,
                      maxlength: 50,
                    },
                        }
                  },

            highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
                $(element)
                    .closest('.help-inline').removeClass('ok'); // display OK icon
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('success').addClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },

            unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change done by hightlight
                $(element)
                    .closest('.control-group').removeClass('error'); // set error class to the control group
            },
 });
```

then if you want to show the messages as soon as you "land" in the input, you can do the validation on focus out: [like in this jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfLrk/2/)

**Snippet**

```
    onfocusout: function (element) {
       $(element).valid();
    },
```